# Test app link with powershell

Tags: powershell, web

I am using powershell to do some monitoring and I want to check if an application's jnlp 
exists on a website and is available for downloading. 
I have the link to the .jnlp and so far I'm downloading the file with .navigate().

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
Try { 
    $ie.navigate("http://bla.com/testApp.jnlp")
} Catch {
    #$_
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I tried to catch an exception by giving invalid filename but it doesn't work. 
Also I thought of downloading the app and try to delete the file afterwards so as to 
check that it actually exists but it would be too slow since I have many jnlps to check.

Is there another more simple and elegant way to do so? I want to avoid the downloading of 
each file I want to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient.aspx) class from .Net? Getting data is simple enough. Like so,

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
try {
    # Download data as string and store the result into $data
    $data = $webclient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/")
} catch [Net.WebException] {
    # A 404 or some other error occured, process the exception here
    $ex = $_
    $ex.Exception
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PowerShell 3.0 or higher, you can use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) to see if a page exists by issuing an HTTP `HEAD` request and checking the status code.

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -uri `http://bla.com/testApp.jnlp` -method head
if ($Result.StatusCode -ne 200){
    # Something other than "OK" was returned.
}
```

This is doable with `System.Net.WebClient` as well but it's a bit more effort.